# Rinkeby is extremely slow at confirming transactions

Tags: rinkeby

Sometimes I am experiencing more than 20 hours waiting for my transactions on Rinkeby Tesnet to be confirmed.
I know I can't start mining myself because I'm not authorized to do so.

What is causing this?
What can I do in such cases?

What I need is to be able to develop, deploy, test (using web3js & Metamask) and then make changes to start all over. I can't wait 20 hours each time I deploy a new version of my Contract.

Thank you

Comment: I haven't ever used the network, but it sounds strange that you can mine on the main net freely but couldn't mine on a test net?
But anyway, the problem is most likely that there are no miners as there are no rewards for doing so.

Comment: While you wait for 20 hours do you see new blocks being mined every 30 seconds or no blocks are mined? You can see new blocks here https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/ Also what is the gasprice that you set?

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem.  It doesn't happen with all transactions.  I've been able to get ordinary transfers of value through in seconds, both from Metamask and from Geth.  But then I submitted a contract creation transaction through my Geth node, and it's been in the "pending" state for 90 minutes and counting.  Avg block time is 15s according to the rinkeby stats page.